# Pivot table with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use Script in Google spreadsheet and it is very great.

I had a problem.

I tried to create (from a piece of data already loaded) to create a Pivot Report .. no problem with the menu selection in the spreadsheet (Menu "date" -> "Pivot Report") ... I could not find a way to create a script that I can do this automatically.

How to create a pivot table in Google Spreadsheet Script?

And 'possible?

Comment: There is no such option available yet in Apps Script. You may file a feature request here http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request%20from%20user

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326172/pivot-table-with-google-script/52601364#52601364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Pivot Table has been created though script, although its not Google's one that you mentioned in your post. See the [Pivot Table through script by Romain Vialard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJJwNrS_dig) which is available in the spreadsheet script galary (just go to the Tools>Script galary from the spreadsheet's menu; once there do a search for Pivot Table, and Romain's comes up.)

Comment: Tools->script gallery is no longer on the menu. Can you provide a direct link to the script?

Answer (score 2):

There's a new feature in Sheets:
Advanced Sheets Service.

It has some more features like creating a Pivot table

> This is an advanced service that must be enabled before use.

This means you need to enable it twice:

1. In Script menu: Resources → Advanced Google Services
2. In Google Api console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/ in `Google Apps APIs → Sheets Api`

Here's the code:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets#create_a_pivot_table

Answer (score 1):

You can use `createDataSourcePivotTable` from the `Range` class as shown in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createDataSourcePivotTable(DataSource)):

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var anchorCell = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('A1');
var dataSource = spreadsheet.getDataSources()[0];

var pivotTable = anchorCell.createDataSourcePivotTable(dataSource);
pivotTable.addRowGroup('dataColumnA');
pivotTable.addColumnGroup('dataColumnB');
pivotTable.addPivotValue('dataColumnC', SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.SUM);
pivotTable.addFilter('dataColumnA', SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextStartsWith('A').build());
```