# JavaScript Method to change PivotTable Data Range Google Docs Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

What is the method to change the data range of a pivot table in a Google Docs spreadsheet?

The documentation for this is not on Google's support site.

Comment: See following answer on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326172/pivot-table-with-google-script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326172/pivot-table-with-google-script/52601364#52601364

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that could help you.

Create a sheet dedicated to your data, row 1 = headers, all other rows = data.

Delete rows with no data.

If for example you use columns A through F, create a Pivot and use this range: SHEET_NAME!A:F

The pivot will "grow" to the news rows because the range is "all the data in the columns A to F".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to modify pivot table settings via Google Apps Script. If you'd like to see this feature please file a feature request on our [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).