# How to update PivotTable with Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table

I need help to update a pivotTable with google app script. Is there a good way to do it?

The pivotTable will create with the following function:

```
function pivotTableTest() {
  // Ask for the source spreadsheet name
  // Has to enter with range!
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sourceSpreadsheet = ui.prompt("Enter the sheet name with range:");
  Logger.log(sourceSpreadsheet.getResponseText());
  Logger.log(sourceSpreadsheet.getSelectedButton());
  
  // Create PivotTable
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange(sourceSpreadsheet.getResponseText());
  var pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('B3').createPivotTable(sourceData);

  // Add Rows
  var pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(3);
```

Now I need a function to add Values to the pivotTable:

```
function addValue() {
  //???????????????????????????????????????
  //pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(31, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.SUM);
}
```

But I don't know how to write the function, because the only way to do this was create a new PivotTable..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This should be very useful: [pivot tables](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/pivot-tables#add_a_pivot_table) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks this could help! But how can I add this to the script?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44048664/4243927) that uses the example @Marios mentions